# problemas al activar una ruta desde un boton en Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

En este proyecto: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-byvfjy?file=src/app/plicas/listado-plicas/listado-plicas.component.html

Cuando entras en Plicas y das al botón "Añadir licitación" quiero que se carge una pagina con el correspondiente formulario

[image: añadir]

Para ello en la template tengo el routerLink apuntando a la nueva ruta

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="false">
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn" routerLink="licitaciones/add">Añadir Licitación</button>
      </div>
```

y en el app-routing.module.ts tengo el path

```
{ path: 'licitaciones/add', component: FormularioLicitacionesComponent },
```

Pero cuando pincho me lleva al Home sin mas

[image: home]

Pero es que si le meto a mano la ruta tampoco me muestra el formulario

[image: licitaciones]

Alguna idea, por favor?

Salu2

Answer (score 0):

La solucion es bien sencilla

```
<button mat-raised-button color="warn" routerLink="/licitaciones/add">Añadir Licitación</button>
```

En la ruta hay que poner al principio el slash y quedaria asi "/licitaciones/add"

Salu2

Answer (score 0):

Modifique la siguiente línea
routerLink="licitaciones/add"
por
routerLink="/licitaciones/add"

Ya que al no poner el "/" no reconoce la ruta